# Exclude starts with but include ends with

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

I can't figure it out myself, I have to match a string what starts with `ASP.` and ends with `_aspx`, but i need to exclude the start of the match (the `ASP.` part).

For example,

```
 string input = "random stack trace text ASP.filename_aspx random text";
 Regex r = new Regex("Regular expression needed!!!");

 var mc = r.Matches(s);

        foreach (var item in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
```

And it have needs to output something like this,

> filename_aspx

Answer (score 6):

That's a job for a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=\bASP\.)\S+_aspx");
```

`(?<=\bASP\.)` ensures that `ASP.` is present just before the starting position of the match, but it doesn't include it in the match result. The `\b` is a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) that asserts that we don't match `WASP`, only `ASP`.

`\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters (this assumes that your filenames don't contain spaces).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you, `ASP\.(.+_.*?)\s`, and here is a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/r/LiwOlffxn7).

**Explanation**

- `ASP\.` - searches for the string `ASP.` to determine a starting position.
- `(.+_.*?)` - `.+` finds any character 1 or more times, `_` matches the underscore to make an assumption we're reaching the end of the string, and `.*?` says get any character 0 or more times but it's a non-greedy match so it will only take as much as necessary until it reaches the next match.
- `\s` - the next match, it looks for a space, and so you get the file name because the `.*?` stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that even without regex (what's more efficient):

```
string text = "blub ASP.filename_aspx foo ASP.filename2_aspx bah ...";
var matches = new List<string>();
int index = text.IndexOf("ASP", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
int endIndex = index >= 0 ? text.IndexOf("_aspx", index + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) : -1;
while (index >= 0 && endIndex >= 0)
{
    index += "ASP.".Length;
    endIndex += "_aspx".Length;
    matches.Add(text.Substring(index, endIndex - index));
    index = text.IndexOf("ASP", endIndex + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    endIndex = index >= 0 ? text.IndexOf("_aspx", index + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) : -1;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/y1UTnv)